# Why isn't my nginx web server handling ttf fonts?

Tags: laravel, nginx, cors, nginx-config

I've been researching this issue where a specific font file isn't rendered on remote sites because of CORS restrictions.

So far I have been able to identify that requests for that url are responding with access-control-allow-origin, but nginx is rejecting requests for that font when made remotely.

I am using laravel and the laravel-cors plugin from spatie, but I wouldn't think that would return header information for a style sheet or font not rendered from laravel routes.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

**My Error**

```
Access to font at 'https://example.com/css/widget-icons/icomoon.ttf?wiodlm' from origin 'http://www.second-example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Header retrieved via curl (It seems to allow curl requests)**

```
curl -I https://example.com/css/widget-icons/icomoon.ttf?wiodlm

HTTP/2 200 
date: Sun, 13 Jan 2019 16:57:34 GMT
content-type: application/x-font-ttf
content-length: 1316
set-cookie: AWSALB=r3yRudj6XwTlfaFzEdtxrecHzLLplOKlpRMbKuqL8InwUQYylNVFaZtmGHK2wQDgjvaXsBtRVcTCyjWidjTFUFmoDzKLBLH0gL6qarns38Qn4FuDNCZogawHtOjD; Expires=Sun, 20 Jan 2019 16:57:34 GMT; Path=/
server: nginx/1.14.1
last-modified: Tue, 25 Dec 2018 05:42:49 GMT
etag: "5c21c359-524"
expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
cache-control: max-age=315360000
access-control-allow-origin: *
accept-ranges: bytes
```

**My nginx config to  Access-Control-Allow-Origin (It's set to the proper case sensitivity).**

```
location ~* .(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|3gp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|flv|mp3|mid|js|css|wml|swf|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        expires max;
}
```

**Mime types added to pass ttf**

```
application/x-font-ttf           ttc ttf;
application/x-font-otf           otf;
application/font-woff                            woff;
application/font-woff2           woff2;
```

Comment: The browser doesn't care about the case of the headers. You should look at a different cause of the issue. You may want to burst the cache; expiration time looks to be very far into the future

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolved this issue by modifying the mime.types used for ttf from application/x-font-ttf to font/ttf.

**my nginx config**

```
    location ~* .(js|css|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header access-control-allow-origin "*";
            expires max;
    }
```

**mime.types file**

```
mime.types edit. 
    application/x-font-ttf           ttc;
    application/x-font-otf           otf;
    application/font-woff2           woff2;
    font/ttf                         ttf;
```

Comment: This saved me too much time I know I would have wasted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar errors when trying to get CORS working properly on nginx + Lumen stack. Eventually, I ended up removing the nginx virtual host side config for enabling CORS and used custom middleware to handle the requests. I haven't used the `laravel-cors` plugin, but for the sake of testing, you may try this simple solution:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];
        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }
        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: this didn't solve my issue, but it's a nice solution to cors issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with nextcloud. It was enough to add woff2

```
   location ~* \.(?:svg|gif|png|html|ttf|woff|woff2|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
        # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
        access_log off;
   }
```