# how to fix 'Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy' Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request only one route

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

[image][image]i'm setting a laravel and vuejs.

CORS plugin for laravel and frontend side i use Axios to call REST api

i got this ERROR
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xx.xxxx.xx' from origin 
 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight 
 request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a 
 preflight request.

```
this is for a vuejs axios setup  **main.js**
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.BASE_URL;
axios.defaults.headers.get['Accepts'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';

  **content.vue file**

  this.loading = true;
      var companyId = this.$route.params.cid;
      var userId = this.$route.params.uid;
      const thisVue = this;
      var formData = new FormData();

  let data = {};

  formData.append("subject", this.title);
  formData.append("content", this.content);
  formData.append("posting_article_url", this.blog_link);
  formData.append("recruitment_tension", this.sel_recruitment_tension);
  formData.append("why_hire_engineer", this.sel_company_hire_engineer);
  formData.append("technique_skill", this.requiredTechniqueSkill);
  formData.append("better_technique_skill",this.betterTechniqueSkillIfThereIs);
  formData.append("personality", this.requiredPersonality);
  formData.append("any_request", this.anyRequest);
  formData.append("location", this.location);
  formData.append("supplement_time", this.supplement_time);
  formData.append("supplement_contract", this.supplement_contract);
  formData.append("en_benefits", this.en_benefits);
  formData.append("recruit_role", this.recruit_role);
  formData.append("how_to_proceed", this.how_to_proceed);
  formData.append("current_structure", this.current_structure);
  if (this.selectedSkill.length > 0)
  {
    let selectedSkills = this.selectedSkill
    .filter(obj => {
      return  obj.id;
    })
    .map(item => {
      return item.id;
    });
    formData.append("skill_keyword", selectedSkills);
  }
  if (this.imageBlob != "") {
    formData.append("image", this.imageBlob, "temp.png");
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < this.sel_schedule.length; i++) {
    formData.append("freelance_type[" + i + "]", this.sel_schedule[i])
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < this.sel_type_of_contract.length; i++) {
    formData.append("contract_type[" + i + "]", this.sel_type_of_contract[i])
  }
    this.loading = false;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:300}, 'slow');
  } else {
     axios
    .post(
      "/xx/xxx/?token=" + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      formData,
      {
        headers: [
            { "X-localization": localStorage.getItem("lan") },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*' },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept '},
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE" },
            { "Access-Control-Max-Age": 3600 }
          ]
      }
    )
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.data.result) {
         if (res.data[0]) {
          this.$toaster.error(res.data[0]);
          this.$store.dispatch("logout");
        }
        if (res.data.errors) {
            for (var i = 0; i < res.data.errors.length; i++) {
              this.$toaster.error(res.data.errors[i].message);
            }
        }
        this.loading = false;
      } else {
        this.$toaster.success(thisVue.$t("success_recruit_add"));
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.$toaster.error(thisVue.$t("err_network"));
    });
  }
```

the error occur only one route rest all are working.
also working on **Postman**

Comment: Your error says a HTTP redirect is not allowed for the preflight OPTIONS request, you now need to debug why the other server is sending this

Comment: @Ferrybig i got error only one route all other are working good and also running well on my local server.

Comment: Could you show the full response, including the path of the original url, and the path of the url the server tries to redirect you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Permanent solution from server side:

The best and secure solution is to allow access control from server end. For laravel you can follow the following  steps:

In `App\Http\Middleware\Cors.php`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS');
}
```

In `App\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

### Temporary solution from browser side:

If you want to disable CORS from browser-end then follow one of the following steps:

**Safari:** Enable the develop menu from `Preferences > Advanced`. Then select “Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions” from the develop menu.

**Chrome (Extension):** Use the Chrome extension [Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)

**Chrome (CMD):** Close all your Chrome browser and services. Then run the following command:

Windows:

```
“C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe” –-allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security --user-data-dir --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating
```

Mac:

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome — args — user-data-dir=”/tmp/chrome_dev_test” — disable-web-security
```

Comment: great effort but, my scenario are different.

Comment: What is your scenario ?

Comment: it has solved my problem, I am facing this for several days

Comment: This will solve the problem on the local machine. But when you go live, the problem persists. It is not a good solution to tell all your users to install an extension or do some settings on their browsers.

Comment: @franc definitely it is not good for server. The solution is for localhost only. In server there are several best practices that you can follow. Here I am sharing one: https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled

Comment: Can you explain from where is exactly opening that 3rd point - Add https://localhost to it’s setting like the screen shot: I am not to find that option

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: I do agree with @franc this is not a good solution and should not be the accepted answer

Comment: @ksugiarto  Could you please  suggest a good solution for localhost ?? This solution is not good for server definitely, for server need to allow the url but in question the url is localhost so the answer should be based on local environment.

Comment: @MdRiadulIslam I am just passing by when searching for my own cors issue, I don't use vue.js. But here the thing, the problem with cors is always about the server, sometimes even we configure the cors correctly but the server response is not proper for that particular request, the front/browser could say it was a cors issue due to some missing cors configuration response from the server. Second, see how you hack the chrome with --disable-web-security, that is definitely something you did with your own risk, hence please don't suggest this risky solution.

Comment: Three, like the previous comment, when you change computer, OS, this will raise again when the real problem is the server. Not to mention the other team member if the author is working with, they will be easily replicate the case, furthermore, the goal of code always to run on the server, not localhost. In short, your solution may be working, but it is not a good solution yet.

Answer (score 14):

The problem comes from your Vue App.

Eg: You're requesting the url below:

```
https://example.com/api/methods/
```

And the backend redirect it to:

```
https://example.com/api/methods
```

Beware of the trailing slash at the end.

Comment: OMG, I never thought about it. Thanks man for saving me.

Answer (score 10):

The issue is from the back-end side in our case is Laravel, in your config/cors.php try to use the below config:

```
'supportsCredentials' => true,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
'exposedHeaders' => [],
'maxAge' => 0,
```

Or you can try to use this code in the top of public/index.php

**Edit**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X- 
Request-With');
```

Comment: still did't work, i change code what you are said but, still face same error.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is from the server side. If you are using express js. Try to install the express cors package on your server.

> ```
> npm install cors
> ```

In your app.js require cors.

> ```
> var cors = require('cors')
> ```

Then, add it as a middleware to your app.

> ```
> app.use(cors())
> ```

You should not experience the cors issue after installing the package.

Comment: Same issue bro even after installing the cors module

Answer (score 2):

We can fix with APP_URL, if you use it as the base url for axios request. Please, make sure your browser root url and APP_URL in .env both are same.

For example, if you run the app on "http://127.0.0.1:8000" then should be the APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

And if you run the app on "http://localhost:8000" then should be the APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

Hope, this will help! And it's tested with laravel6.x

Answer (score 1):

The cors (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) handle by server side. If you are come from laravel end so the **barryvdh/laravel-cors** package is help to solve this error

> url: 
>   https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some misconfiguration either on the webserver side or Laravel side. Perhaps this solution might help you: [Why isn't my nginx web server handling ttf fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54171710/why-isnt-my-nginx-web-server-handling-ttf-fonts/54190520#54190520).

Pay close attention to the `OPTIONS` method, since this enables the support for Preflight.

Comment: why its not working only one route?  all other routes are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling this flag worked for me:
chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests

Answer (score -1):

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_origin: ["*"]
        allow_headers: ["*"]
        allow_methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
        max_age: 3600
        origin_regex: false
    paths:
        '^/': ~
```

> add in nelmio_cors /packge/nelmio_cors

Answer (score -1):

Steps

1. Go to this link
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf
2. download it
3. switch on the chrome web browser  extension
4. Check your http link
5. example http to https of the remote url.
   do the get api.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).