# Why am I getting the unhandled rejection error for my web application?

Tags: reactjs, web-development-server

I recently started making a web application for wannabe writers.
Here, one can signup and login. And can create genres and write into them.
I'm building this application using ReactJS.

Now, I'm getting error whenever I try to create a new genre.

The error looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l69H.jpg

**AddGenre.js File**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import { notify } from 'react-notify-toast';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../styles.css';
import axiosInstance from '../Constants/AxiosCall';


class AddGenre extends Component {
  // initialize state
  state = {
    name: '',
    desc: '',
  }

  // handle user input
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  // handle add category request
  handleAddGenre = () => {
    const payload = new FormData();
    payload.set('name', this.state.name);
    payload.set('desc', this.state.desc);

    // send POST request to API
    axiosInstance.post('genre', payload)
      .then((response) => {
        notify.show(response.data.message, 'success', 4000);
        this.props
          .history
          .push('/genres');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        notify.show(error.response.data.message, 'error', 4000);
      });
  }

  // render add category form
  render() {
    const style = {
      marginLeft: 20,
      width: 340,
    };
    const divstyle = {
      width: 430,
      margin: 'auto',
      textAlign: 'left',
      paddingLeft: 20,
    };
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div className="main">
          <div className="inputs" style={{ paddingTop: '150px' }}>
            <Paper zDepth={2} style={divstyle}>
              <p className="heading"><b>ADD GENRE</b></p>

              <TextField
                floatingLabelText="Name"
                name="name"
                value={this.state.name}
                style={style}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              /><br /><br />

              <TextField
                floatingLabelText="Description"
                name="desc"
                value={this.state.desc}
                style={style}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              /><br /><br /><br />

              <div className="buttons">
                <button className="network" id="one" onClick={(event => this.handleAddGenre(event))}>ADD</button>
                <Link to="/genres"><button className="network" id="two">CANCEL</button></Link><br /><br /><br />

              </div>

            </Paper><br />

          </div>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default AddGenre;
```

The hierarchy of the project looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlbXe.jpg

Please help by telling me to resolve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like in your `.catch()` the error does not have a `response` object.

Change your `.catch` to

```
.catch((error) => {
     console.log("error is", error);
     //notify.show(error, 'error', 4000);
 })
```

This should at least solve your current error.

Comment: I made changes in catch as you told. I'm getting this error now...........................Unhandled Rejection (Error): Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: Network Error). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in span (created by Toast)
    in div (created by Toast)
    in Toast

Comment: @NehaChaudhary Can you console.log the error like i have done and tell me what the log is?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://yummy-recipe-flaskapi.herokuapp.com/api/v1/genre' from origin 'http://localhost:3007' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
AddGenre.js:42 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at AddGenre.js:42

Comment: Well you need to solve the CORS error now. Your api request is getting blocked by cors policy.

Comment: How do I do it? I have no clue. Can you please help?

Comment: @NehaChaudhary this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212220/how-to-fix-access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-redirect-i