# Laravel Cors error - URL has been blocked

Tags: laravel, cors, laravel-6

I tried to create authentication with cas but I ran into this problem. I placed my routes both in `web.php` and in `api.php`, but got the same result. Usually I use header permission and it works, but now it doesn't.

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token,
 Authorization, Origin'); header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, PUT');
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://example/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Flookups'
>   (redirected from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/lookups') from origin
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
>   HTTP ok status.

Comment: in `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');` the `*` in no longer supported by browsers. You need to list all all allowed domains one by one.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212220/how-to-fix-access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-redirect-i

Comment: " * ", I took it from an applications where I use it, and works. I will look more on that questions. Thanks!

Comment: The specific problem is that your server is responding to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request with some HTTP status code other than 200 OK. What’s the exact HTTP status code the server’s responding with? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check.

Answer (score 1):

the **barryvdh/laravel-cors** package is helpful to solve this error, download it here:

[barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Comment: After publishing the config file, be sure to add the path(s) you need to make exceptions for. Example: `'paths' => ['api/*',],`