# NuxtJS - After fetching data from the external API, the console outputs an error CORS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

With news.vue ( http://localhost:3000/news ), I was able to request an external API using Fetch API and get the article data in JSON format.

```
<section class="section-news">
  <div
    v-if="articles != null"
    class="section-news__cards"
  >
    <div
      v-for="article in articles.data.contents"
      :key="article.id"
      class="section-news__card"
    >
      <div class="section-news__media image_wrapper">
        <img
          :src="article.eyecatch"
          alt="note eyecatch"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="section-news__body">
        <div class="section-news__body-date">{{ article.publishAt }}</div>
        <p class="section-news__body-description">{{ article.body }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

However, when the screen transitioned from index.vue ( http://localhost:3000/ ) or about.vue ( http://localhost:3000/about ) to news.vue ( http://localhost:3000/news ), the I get the following error in the console Can someone please explain this problem? I want to know how I can solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the CORS configuration isn't setup correctly, the browser console will present an error like "Cross-Origin Request Blocked"; This is used to explicitly allow some cross-origin requests while rejecting others. For example, if a site offers an embeddable service, it may be necessary to relax certain restrictions.

We usually handle this configuration in back-end but you can fix this on your local system by adding Allow-Control-Allow-Origin to your chrome browser and adding your localhost in it. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212220/how-to-fix-access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-redirect-i/54215316) that might help you down the line.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was at nuxt-link. Replacing nuxt-link with a-tag solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there was a problem with the handling of .
Replacing  with  worked correctly.