# Axios CORS issue on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, axios, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a fastapi host on aws Elastic Beanstalk. I want to build a vue app to interact with it.

But, when I try

```
const res = await axios.post(baseUrl, 
        {
          HMA_lat: 22.33012,
          HMA_Lng: 114.1641913,
          blg_age: 19
        },
        {
          headers:{
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
        }
      )
```

in the brower console, I got the CORS error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://..... (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Should I modify seeting in the Elastic Beanstalk server? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this on your local system by adding Allow-Control-Allow-Origin to your chrome browser and adding your localhost in it. There is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212220/how-to-fix-access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-redirect-i/54215316) question that might help you down the line.

Comment: I have tried some plugins. But still get the error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.0.147/predict. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed).`

Comment: should I change my code in fastapi? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/

Comment: @JOHN If the CORS configuration isn't setup correctly, the browser console will present. check you'r configs

Answer (score 0):

I need to add CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) middleware in FastAPI

Reference: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/