# Data Not Displaying In Angular with Laravel API

Tags: php, mysql, angular, laravel

working with Laravel back end and Angular front end. I have following code segments in Angular, employee.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/service/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: whitespace
  // tslint:disable-next-line: typedef-whitespace
  employees: any;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmployeesData();
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
  getEmployeesData() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(res => {
      this.employees = res;
    });
  }

}
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  // tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
  getData() {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee');
  }

 
}
```

employee.component.html

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let emp of employees">
            <th scope="row">{{emp.id}}</th>
            <th> {{emp.name}}</th>
            <th>{{emp.email}}</th>
            <th> {{emp.salary}}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and my Laravel api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('employee','EmployeeController@getEmployee');

Route::get('employee/{id}','EmployeeController@getEmployeeById');

Route::post('addEmployee','EmployeeController@addEmployee');

Route::put('updateEmployee/{id}','EmployeeController@updateEmployee');

Route::delete('deleteEmployee/{id}','EmployeeController@deleteEmployee');
```

but in my Angular html file not database employees data. not any errors here. both Angular and Laravel projects are running. how could I fix this problem?

**Edit**
My Error in Console
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

`127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED`

`ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee", ok: false, …}`

Comment: check your network tab and share api response.

Comment: how could I do this?

Comment: in chrome ctrl+shift+j or ctrl+shift+i and go to network tab and hit your api. here you will see the details of api. response or error of api. and in console tab you can see your errors.

Comment: yes I have error msg in console. please see edited answer

Comment: it's a cross origin issue. you need to fix this in your laravel application by allowing the domain to access api. there are plenty of solutions available about cross origin issue.

Comment: do you have any solutions suggest

Comment: actually i am a frontend dev so i don't know much about laravel. but you can try this [solution](https://therichpost.com/solved-laravel-angular-cors-issue/).

Comment: you can update the `config/cors.php` file to accept localhost:4200

Comment: I got success using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212220/how-to-fix-access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-redirect-i

Answer (score 0):

Your requests are blocked by CORS. In order to fix your issue you should try updating `cors.php` to allow your host (remember to include the port too, as it is important).

Alternatively, you may follow [Laravel 5.1 API Enable Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors) albeit old, the concepts do apply.

**Edited**: as per comments on the question, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212220/how-to-fix-access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-redirect-i) could be useful too.