# HTTP flutter problem with json file (API)

Tags: json, flutter, api, response, host

I was working on a project that uses flutter for UI and HTTP requests that takes data from json file that i wrote and hosted by myself ( http://json-crud-file.epizy.com/file/file )

I used function below to fetch data :

```
Future fetchData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('http://json-crud-file.epizy.com/file/file'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
    } else {
      print('faild fetching');
    }
  }
```

Then i get that error in console :

```
I/flutter (11924): <html><body><script>document.cookie="_test=4c9ff9225c7521d4102dc4ecb6f6be1e ; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/" ;document.location.href="http://json-crud-file.epizy.com/file/file?i=1";</script></body></html>
```

But when i use the same code but in diffrent json file in https://dummyjson.com/products i get json response code below:

```
  Future fetchData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://dummyjson.com/products'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
    } else {
      print('faild fetching');
    }
  }
```

response :

```
{"products":[{"id":1,"title":"iPhone 9","description":"An apple mobile which is nothing like apple","price":549,"discountPercentage":12.96,"rating":4.69,"stock":94,"brand":"Apple","category":"smartphones","thumbnail":"https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/thumbnail.jpg","images":["https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/1.jpg","https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/2.jpg","https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/3.jpg","https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/4.jpg","https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/thumbnail.jpg"]},{"id":2,"title":"iPhone X","description":"SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super Retina HD display with OLED technology A12 Bionic chip with ...","price":899,"discountPercentage":17.94,"rating":4.44,"stock":34,"brand":"Apple","category":"smartphones","thumbnail":"https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/thumbnail.jpg","images":["https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/1.jpg","https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/2.jpg","https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/3.jpg","https:/}
```

Comment: are you building web app or mobile app?

Comment: i just try and run on web app, the error is `blocked by CORS policy` . try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54901498/12838877